# Why does quoting matter with getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a dom object like this within an html page:

```
<textarea id="owctl7fzk">​foo</textarea>
```

When I try to access it with `getElementById` without quoting the id, it returns `null`.

```
window.document.getElementById(owctl7fzk)
```

but when I put the id within single or double quotes, it selects the object:

```
window.document.getElementById('owctl7fzk')
window.document.getElementById("owctl7fzk")
```

Why does the quotation matter in this case? In general, when you can you omit and when can you not?

**Edit** In the code I presented above, the id is a hexatridecimal number. I previously had a decimal number without quotes as id, and it had no problem. Why was that?

Comment: Simply because `getElementById` expects a string. If browsers would not create variables in global scope for elements with IDs, `getElementById(owctl7fzk)` would actually throw an error because `owctl7fzk` is an undefined variable.

Comment: @FelixKling browsers seriously do that? That's crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when the ID is within a quote, its a string that is used to identify the ID attribute, otherwise it's reference as a variable. If you are performing `window.document.getElementById(owctl7fzk)`, javascript is searching for a variable named `owctl7fzk`. If you used `var owctl7fzk = 'owctl7fzk'`, it shall work

Answer (score 3):

`getElementById(owctl7fzk)` selects the element whose `id` attribute is equal to the value of the `owctl7fzk` **variable**:

```
var owctl7fzk = "the_id";
var element = document.getElementById(owctl7fzk);
```

`owctl7fzk` is definitely not the same as `"owctl7fzk"`, because the former is a variable name, while the latter is a string.

This is how JavaScript works. Just because you can omit the quotes in HTML doesn't mean that you can do the same in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in quotes because you are passing a string parameter to the getElementById method. Strings need to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, as in most languages, the parser understands a quoted value to be a "string" and an unquoted one to be an identifier (this is oversimplifying, and in reality, it's the [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), not the parser).

Specific to your question, an element's id is a string, and so must be represented as a string in your source. You can use a variable (represented in code by an identifier of your choice) to hold this string or to hold the element itself:

```
var my_id = "owctl7fzk";
var elem = document.getElementById(my_id);
alert( my_id + " is the same as " + elem.id );
```