# How do I fix this code regarding getelementbyid [Javascript]?

Tags: javascript

So I'm currently taking a coding class and am not very well versed in coding. I'm having trouble with a getelementbyid block which isn't writing my looped array for an assignment. Could anyone help me out?

Here's the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Looping Assignment
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 align=center>Name and Grades</h1>
  <p id="message"> Name </p>
  <p id="message2"> Grade </p>

  <script>
    var input = []
    var message = " "
    var message2 = " "

    var n = 0
    var i = 1
    var names = n
    var grade = i
    for (n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
      var names = n + 1
      input[n] = window.prompt("Enter First Name" + names)
      message += "Your name is " + input[n] + "<br>"
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      input[i] = window.prompt("Enter Grade (numerical value)" + grade)
      message2 += "Grade " + i + " is " + input[i] + "<br>"
    }

    document.getElementById(message).innerHTML = "your name is " + input[n] + "<br>"
    document.getElementById(message2).innerHTML = "Grade" + i + " is " + input[i] + "<br"
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is invalid in a lot of ways. You need to close your for loops and your selectors have to be strings, a.e. `document.getElementById("message")` not `document.getElementById(message)`

Comment: @SlavicMilk can you explain more about the expected input and output of the program so that i can provide you a better solution

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by closing the for loops, that's what I thought too when I saw their snippet, but the closing } is on the same line instead of the next one. (Improper indentation)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15696292/8376184

Comment: @David You're right, I saw that after I started writing an answer. I missed it when I looked, but I think the lack of formatting threw me off *shrug*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your selectors are strings

   - `document.getElementById("message");` not `document.getElementById(message);`
2. Make sure you end your lines of code with semi-colons. This is **not optional** even though the code will attempt to run without them.
3. Change your output to render your accumulated data - right now you're overwriting your output every time you loop.

**Note:** I don't know what you're doing with the numerical value inside of the `prompt` methods (`names` and `grade` ) so I didn't touch it.

---

### Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Looping Assignment
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 align=center>Name and Grades</h1>
  <p id="message"> Name </p>
  <p id="message2"> Grade </p>

  <script>
    var input = [];

    var message = " ";
    var message2 = " ";

    var n = 0;
    var i = 1;
    var names = n;
    var grade = i;
    for (n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
      var names = n + 1
      input[n] = window.prompt("Enter First Name " + names)
      message += "Your name is " + input[n] + "<br>";
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      input[i] = window.prompt("Enter Grade (numerical value) " + grade)
      message2 += "Grade " + i + " is " + input[i] + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = message2 + "<br>";
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variables and your *id*-s have the same names. By doing `getElementbyId(message)` you are passing the variables' values instead of the fixed *id* you gave to your elements.

You need to put the *id*-s in quotes as follows:

```
document.getElementById("message")
document.getElementById("message2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested at my end and this is working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Looping Assignment
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 align=center>Name and Grades</h1>
    <p id="message"> Name </p>
    <p id="message2"> Grade </p>

    <script>
        var input = []

        var message = " "
        var message2 = " "

        var n = 0
        var i = 1
        var names = n
        var grade = i
        for (n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
            var names = n + 1
            input[n] = window.prompt("Enter First Name" + names)
            message += "Your name is " + input[n] + "<br>"
        }

        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            input[i] = window.prompt("Enter Grade (numerical value)" + grade)
            message2 += "Grade " + i + " is " + input[i] + "<br>"
        }

        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "your name is " + input[n] + "<br>"
        document.getElementById('message2').innerHTML = "Grade" + i + " is " + input[i] + "<br"


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

error:- 
    The id of getElementbyId must be in quotes

Answer (score 0):

@SlavicMilk

**Below should be sufficient for your assignment:**

HTML (index.html):

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">Name and Grades</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JS (script.js):

```
let student = []

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  student[i] = {
    "name": window.prompt(`Enter Name ${i + 1}`),
    "grade": window.prompt(`Enter Grade (numerical value) ${i + 1}`)
  }
}

document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = student.map(student => {
  return `<tr><td>${student.name}</td><td>${student.grade}</td></tr>`
})
```

Comment: Thank you. To follow up on your comment, I was told to write the first name and grades of a person in an array that is supposed to loop. I ended up breaking up classes for a bit for break and when I came back I didn't know what I was looking at. I really need to start writing code comments.

Comment: @SlavicMilk I have edited my answer as you required: "first name and grades of a person in an array that is supposed to loop"